# Instagram Filters RGBA Values

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, image-processing, air, instagram-api

I need to add image filters to an iOS app that is being developed using Adobe Air.

To be more specific, i need to apply the following filters (or similar):

1. Nashville
2. Hemingway
3. Jarques
4. Cross Process
5. Hazy Days

You can use this page as a reference http://techslides.com/demos/canvas/instagram.html

I know how to apply filters to a BitmapData on AS3, but i need the RGBA values of the above filters, does anyone knows them or knows how to obtain them?

I need something like the following values:

```
    private static const NASHVILLE_FILTER_MATRIX: Array = [
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, //R
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, //G
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, //B
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0  //A
    ];
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to to check this framework [GPUImage](https://github.com/inspirit/GPUImage/blob/master/examples/GPUImageShowcase.as) 
There is an example [here](https://github.com/inspirit/GPUImage/blob/master/examples/GPUImageShowcase.as)

You can create filters like:

```
  // creating GPU Image
  _gpuImg = new GPUImage();
  _gpuImg.init(context3D, antiAlias, false, stageW, stageH, streamW, streamH);

  // saving all filters
  _imageProcessors = new Vector.<IGPUImageProcessor>();

  // setup filters
  var _gpuSepia:GPUImageSepia = new GPUImageSepia();
  var _gpuGauss:GPUImageGaussianBlur = new GPUImageGaussianBlur(1.0, 4);
  var _gpuGray:GPUImageGrayscale = new GPUImageGrayscale();

  // Bloom Filter            
  var bloomEffect:GPUImageBloomEffect = new GPUImageBloomEffect(GPUImageBloomEffect.PRESET_DESATURATED, 4);
  bloomEffect.initPreset(GPUImageBloomEffect.PRESET_SATURATED);
  // TiltShift
  var tiltShift:GPUImageTiltShiftEffect = new GPUImageTiltShiftEffect(2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2);

  // adding filter to image processor
  _imageProcessors.push(bloomEffect);

  // adding processor to the respective GPU Image
  _gpuImg.addProcessor(_imageProcessors[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I end up using the library you are proposing, but i was not able to implement the filters described in the Question. I would like to share the implementation of other Instagram-Like filters, but i don't know if i should for copyright reasons. Can i?